# Windows phone 7.1, Listpicker fullmodeitemtemplate binding text

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, listpicker

i'm trying to change the font size for my items in a listpicker.
I use a fullmodeitemtemplate to be able to change fontsize etc.

The problem is that i have no idea how to bind the text for the items in the template

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="PickerFullModeItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="16 21 0 20" Background="Orange" Width="110" Height="110" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="{WHAT TO TYPE HERE?}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" FontSize="36"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

I populate my listpicker by setting the itemsource in C# like this

```
foreach (Item i in weight)
            {
                sourceInput.Add(i.name);
            }
        }
        InputSelector.ItemsSource = sourceInput;
```

This leaves me with an itemsource list only containing strings, then i dont know how to bind the text for each item. I read some post on how to do it when the itemsource list is in this format

```
source.Add(new Cities() { Name = "Mexico", Country = "MX", Language = "Spanish" });

        this.listPicker.ItemsSource = source;
```

and then the xaml part is something like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

**UPDATE**

i found the correct binding for binding to the sourceitems.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True}"/>
```

Looks like thats the way to go, then the source items get binded to the textblock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be adding objects of type `Cities` to your `sourceInput` collection.

Typing `Text="{Binding Name}"` is correct.

Most likely your Cities class just doesn't implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface. You should notify the UI each time you update the Name and other properties you have bound your UI elements to.

Comment: Well that "Cities" list was from a post i found on the interwebs, however i found the correct binding for my case :) see my update, Thx for the quick reply thou :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

it is cool but for the listpicker there is also DisplayMemberPath property so,

on listpicker add :

DisplayMemberPath="Name"